# Prevent Azure Log Analytics from incorrectly assuming time range is set in query

Tags: azure, azure-monitor

I have a log analytics query that looks for events that span certain time. Along the lines of

```
SomeTable
| summarize StartTime = min(TimeGenerated), EndTime = max(TimeGenerated) by EventId
| where EndTime - StartTime > 15m
```

Problem is that the presence of the `15m` constant makes the portal think that I am limiting the time range in the query—even though I obviously am not, because there is no constraint for the TimeGenerated column—, switches the time range selector to [image: Time Range: Set in query] and prompltly goes on to complain that the query is taking too much resources, because it's querying the whole month of data. And when I select the time range, it keeps reverting back to Set in query.

Is there a way to indicate that even though there is a timespan constant, it does not set time range, so the selector stops switching to Set in query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the check is for `where` constraint on a value of type `datetime` or `timespan`, so rewriting the condition to

```
| extend Minutes = (EndTime - StartTime)/1m | where Minutes > 15
```

successfully hides it from the time range detection logic. It's ugly, but it's best I came up with so far.